# Regular matrix definition : counter example with AB=I but BA<>I

Tags: matrices, examples-counterexamples, inverse

Definition : $A$ is a regular matrix (has an inverse) if there exists a matrix $B$ such that $A\times B=I$ and $B\times A=I$.
I am looking for an example of a singular matrix $A$ where there is a matrix $B$ such that $A\times B=I$ but $B\times A\neq I$.
Edit : the context of the question : I wanted to show my students that in order to prove a matrix $A$ is regular, we need to show $A\times B=I$ **and** $B\times A=I$. I wanted to illustrate this point with a counter-example ... but could not find one for the reason stated below.
But then, since inverse is a concept for square matrices (otherwise we have a generalization : the pseudo-inverse concept for non square matrix), and as showed for square matrices when we have $A\times B=I$ then we have $B\times A=I$, why do we have in the definition the need to show $A\times B=I$ **and** $B\times A=I$ ?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices of the same size, it turns out that $AB = I$ iff $BA = I$. If $A$ isn't required to be square then you can find examples where there exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB = I$ but no matrix $C$ such that $CA = I$ and vice versa.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : $AB=I iff BA=I$ OK (if $AB=I$, $det(B)\neq 0$ so $B$ regular $A=B^-1$ so $BA=I$. <br/> Example of A such that $AB=I$ and no $CA=I$ ?

Comment: My demonstration above is not convincing since when I use the fact that $B^{-1}=A$ to show $BA=I$ I use the property of the inverse definition $A\times B=B\times A$ ... José Carlo's still stands.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such example. Since $A$ is singular, $\det(A\times B)=\det(A)\det(B)=0$, which is impossible, since $\det(\operatorname{Id})=1$.

Comment: Exact (what a shame on me I forgot to use det !). But then, why do we insist in the definition that $A\times B=I$ and $B\times A=I$ ?

Comment: Perhaps because in general, for non-square matrices, even if there is a matrix $B$ such that $A\times B=\operatorname{Id}$, it is generally not true that $B\times A=\operatorname{Id}$.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists $B$ such that $AB=I_n$ then $BA=I_n$ because $f:M\mapsto AM$ is linear, if $AM=0$, we have $M=I_n M=BAM=0$, the injectivity of $f$ implies its surjectivity because $\dim\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is finite. Hence there exists $C$ such that $CA=I_n$, but $B=\underbrace{CA}_{=I_n}B=C\underbrace{AB}_{=I_n}=C$ so $BA=I_n$.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for square matrices, such $A$ cannot exist, as other answers show.

If you are looking for **non-square** matrices, such examples exist. Any $m \times n$ matrix such that $rank(A)=m <n$ satisfies this property.

Comment: example : <br/> $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)=(1)$ $\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$

Comment: @user1771398 As I said, ANY matrix of full rank is an example ;)

Comment: I just need one example to show :)

Comment: @user1771398 More interesting is that, in this case, for each such $A$ you can find infinitely many $B$'s which work. In your example $$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ x \end{array}\right)=(1) \\ \left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 0 \end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b\\ 0 & 0 \end{array}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

example : 
 
$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)=(1)$ but $\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)$ cannot be $I$ $\forall a,b$

Comment: Followinf N.S.'s idea : $A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
B & C\end{array}\right) with B\in\mathcal{GL(p)}$ and $C\in\mathcal{M}_{p,q}$ $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
B & C\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
B^{\{-1\}}\\
0_{\{q,q\}}
\end{array}\right)=(I_{p})$ $\left(\begin{array}{c}
D\\
E
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
CA & CB\\
DA & DB
\end{array}\right)$with $CA=I$ therefore $C=A^{\{-1\}}$, $CB=0$therefore $B=0$since
$C$ regular, then $DB=0$ cannot be 1.